# Difference between "normal person" and "average person"

Tags: differences

Is there any difference between *normal person* and *average person*? Can I use these interchangeably?

Comment: In general, *normal* is subjective, while *average* is more objective (even quantifiable).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Normal* has societal connotations and can vary according to perception, experience, culture, politics and period of history, whilst *average* usually refers to the results of statistical measurements related to groups of people.

Answer (score 2):

It depends very much on the context. *Normal* can have a variety of meanings, as can *average*. If you're talking about test scores for example, or anything involving quantities, you'll want to use *average* and not *normal*. However, if you're talking about behavior, they're pretty much interchangeable.

Answer (score 0):

An "average" person is a normal person BY DEFINITION.

"Normal" means "close to" average (in statistics), but plus or minus. It is this "plus or minus" part that allows "normal" to be NOT average. Even so, it would mean that the deviation from average is a "normal" or usual amount, and not "way out."

Answer (score 0):

In the world of medical writing, *asymptomatic* is sometimes used instead of *normal.* The idea is that referring to people as *normal* implies that other people are *abnormal.* *Healthy* was used in the same way, but that implies *unhealthy,* which eventually became a pejorative.